# MYSQL getting 'column not found: 1054 Unknown column' error

Tags: mysql, sql

firstly, selecting data from table using this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=102030;
```

```json
{
  "user_id": 102030,
  "social_id": null,
  "user_name": "user_734747",
  "full_name": null,
  "email": null,
  "phone": "1234567890",
  "profile_image": null,
  "referral_code": "rbNqMtqL",
  "created_at": "2022-11-06 10:22:36"
}
```

this is the JSON format of the result

## **Problem**

When executing another statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE referral_code="rbNqMtqL";
```

it is throwing an error

> ```
> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rbNqMtqL' in 'where clause
> ```

actually, sql **replacing** this referral_code column with it's previous value

How to fix this issue?

Comment: The removal of `"`, I assume was occurring at the PHP level.

Comment: Please add table definition as text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised that your query didn't work.  But in any case, what is happening is that the double quotes on the RHS of the `WHERE` clause are being interpreted as a column name.  To fix this, use single quotes:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE referral_code = 'rbNqMtqL';
```

Comment: record referral_code = rbNqMtqL exist but still fetchObject() returning false

Comment: @AKP fetchObject() is not a mysql thing what else are you using?